# AMP HTML: amp-render is rendering content at zero height

Tags: css, amp-html

I hope someone may be able to enlighten me on the following.

I have some experience with mostly static AMP (Accelerated Mobile Pages) for websites, but am currently working on a fairly complex page layout that pulls in some extra data based on the user's level of authorisation.

Specifically, I'm building an HTML5 description list (`<dl>`, `<dt>`, `<dd>`) that is of varying length depending on the attributes being present (or not) on the entity the page represents. I am then using [amp-render](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-render/?format=websites) to pull in additional `dt`/`dd` pairs (or not) from a dynamic API endpoint, depending on the current user's level of authorisation within the application.

Technically this is working completely as expected, but I cannot figure out the correct layout/CSS to render the resulting DOM elements to the page: they're in an AMP-generated `div` that has a CSS-forced `height: 0` so invisble.

My raw page looks something like this:

```html
    <amp-render 
      src="/api/data-source/1234" 
      credentials="include" 
      xssi-prefix=")]}\*" 
      layout="flex-item">
      <template type="amp-mustache">
        <dl>
          <dt>1st item</dt>
          <dd>Definition</dd>
          <dt>2nd item</dt>
          <dd>Definition</dd>
          {{#isAuthorised}}
          <dt>3rd item</dt>
          <dd>
              <ul>
                  {{#array}}
                  <li>{{name}}</li>
                  {{/array}}
              </ul>
          </dd>
          {{/isAuthorised}}
        </dl>
      </template>
    </amp-render>
```

To clarify: the API, JSON, and Mustache template are all working as expected, with the correct HTML returned by the AMP framework.

The problem is that the `<dl>` is immediately contained by the following:

```css
    .i-amphtml-blurry-placeholder, .i-amphtml-fill-content {
        display: block;
        height: 0;
        max-height: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        min-width: 100%;
        width: 0;
        margin: auto;
    }
```

```html
<div i-amphtml-rendered="true" class="i-amphtml-fill-content" loading="auto" aria-live="polite"> ... </div>
```

Given that the `i-amphtml-*` classes are illegal to style with custom CSS, this is where I've come unstuck. No variation of [layouts](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/amp-html-layout/?format=websites#layout) on `amp-render`, nor other containing elements and CSS, are generating the expected result of the definition list actually being visible on the page.

If I wrap `amp-render` itself in a `div` with a specified height then the rendered definition list shows as expected - but there's no way to know what height the `dl` should be, so this isn't a solution for anything more than sanity checking.

Can anyone help?

Surely this is not impossible to achieve? I understand one of the core aims of AMP is to minimise (if not eliminate) page jump as items render in the browser, but surely returning data of variable length is not an uncommon occurrence and there is a way to do what I'm attempting? Or have I missed something incredibly obvious?

(To pre-empty any questions about other styles: I've also tried stripping out all other CSS from the page and there is no difference in what I've managed to display.)

Answer (score 0):

We had similar problems with `amp-list`. The same approach may work for `amp-render`. Separate `amp-render` and `template` and link with an ID (see the amp doc for an example). Move render to page bottom (before `</body>`). Add a minimal height value to render. Set width to auto. When we use this approach for list, the list length will be set to the actual length (as determined by amp runtime). This approach **may** work for render. Note: you cannot control `i-amphtml-*` so don't look for override solutions there (and your page may be invalid if you do try to override).

Comment: Thanks Jay. I've not managed to fix it yet but that certainly feels like it's going in the right direction.

`amp-render` seems to render at the point it is inserted on the page, so I've kept that where it is and moved `template` to just before `</body>` instead. 

No luck with the `min-height` (I assume you meant via CSS rather than the `height` attribute on the tag?) as yet - do you know what layout type you were using on your `amp-list` instance?

Comment: IMHO you cannot move template. template children (HTML elements) need to be at the target location. But the list/render function does not. For list we do as above. And you'll want to use height= and width=auto in render (not as CSS) where the height value equals a single row. For list, the amp-runtime will size the height equal to the items between your template open/close delimiters. I am 100% confident the above works for list. I have not reused your example to check it locally (am away from my dev workstation).

Comment: Right, got you. Sadly `amp-render` renders from the `template` at the point that it, `amp-render`, is on the page, and none of those height tweaks seem to be working. Very frustrating, but thanks for your help - good to know what may solve any such problems on 'amp-list'!